# Socket server is running but client can't connect

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have setup a Node.js server with Socket.io using HTTPS:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');
var options = {
    key:    fs.readFileSync('commercial.key', 'utf8'),
    cert:   fs.readFileSync('commercial.crt', 'utf8'),
    ca:     fs.readFileSync('ca_chain.crt', 'utf8')
};
var server = https.createServer(options, app);
server.listen(3000);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(client){
  //console.log('IO Connection');
  var socket_id = client.id;

  console.log(socket_id + " connected");
});
```

After starting this server, it's running fine. Clients can connect to it. But, after a few hours, new clients can't connect but old clients - the clients connected before - can still interact with the server.

I just have about 200 ccu and I checked RAM, CPU of VPS, all are fine. I also checked the log file and no errors founded.

[image: Client Error]

Anyone can tell me that the setup of server is true or any problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some days research, I don't know why but when i change the config of file /etc/security/limits like this:

```
* soft nofile 65535
* hard nofile 65535
root soft nofile 65535
root hard nofile 65535
```

My server seem to be working well. I posted to anyone that have the problem like me, but if someone have the explanation please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a seperate port for socket.io

```
 var socket_con = http.createServer(function(socket) {

    console.log("socket created=====");
    console.log(socket);
    }).listen(8000);
```

//socket timeout configuration

```
   var mobileData ={  log: true , "close timeout": 120  , "heartbeat timeout": 120   , "heartbeat interval": 30  , "transports": ["websocket"],'disconnected':true};
```

//socket defination

```
  io.listen(socket_con, mobileData).on('connection', function(client){
  //console.log('IO Connection');
  var socket_id = client.id;

  console.log(socket_id + " connected");
});
```

Comment: So i need require http too? 
Can you please explain why i need to define a seperate port for socket.io? Because if i have wrong setup, why the server can run fine for a while?
Anyway, thank you. I'll try your solution and feed back soon.